# How to repeat the last :load command in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

The GHCi help page tells me that I can enter a single `:` to repeat the previous command.

But this does not seem to work with all commands. For instance, when I call up the help page with `:?`, I can show it again by just entering `:`. But when I load a file with `:l myfile` a later input of just `:` will actually unload my file.

Am I doing something wrong or did I misunderstand the help page?

Comment: Is `:r` what you want, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess: `:` repeats the `:l` part, but not the `:l myfile` part. That's probably an oversight or bug.

In the meantime, `:r`, short for `:reload`, will load your file again.